# How to determine whether the following series converges uniformly (and pointwise)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I want to know what the steps are to determine whether the following series converge 1) pointwise  and 2) uniformly.  And how to show if it converges(or doesn't).   $\sum \frac{1}{x^k+1}$ on the interval (1,infinity)  I've tried on myself for hours but couldn't find a way (tried M-weierstrass but that didn't work out well)

Comment: Pointwise is straightforward enough, it should not be difficult to give a simple upper bound on the sum of absolute values in order to deduce absolute convergence (assuming you intend $k \geq 0$). Work this out and then ping me again about the uniformity part if you're still stuck on it.

Comment: 1/(x^k +1)  < 1/(x^k)=   (1/x)^k    is a geometric series so it converges, right?

Comment: That is what I had in mind, yes.

Comment: But the step to uniform convergence is the one I totally lose my mind.   I tried taking the derivative but I end up getting that the optimal value for  x is 0 ( that is not in the domain) and the domain is closed so filling in x=1 to get a M-weierstrass upper bound is also not possible

Comment: So you did an upper bound comparison to get pointwise convergence. But the sum that you compared to does not converge uniformly (indeed, you can use the explicit formula for the partial sums to see this). So that doesn't give uniform convergence. To get a *failure* of uniform convergence, you would want to give a *lower* bound on the tail $\sum_{k=N}^\infty \frac{1}{x^k+1}$. Ideally that lower bound would be just a bit smaller than $\sum_{k=N}^\infty x^{-k}$, like say $\sum_{k=N}^\infty x^{-k}/2$. Can you prove a bound like that eventually holds?

Comment: I've read your comment a few times, but I don't understand how this helps with checking if it converges uniformly .  I think that you can make $\sum$ 1/(x^k+1) small for all x, by taking the limit to infinity (right?). On your second question :  doesn't that depend on the value of x ?

Comment: Because all the terms are positive, $|S_n(x)-S(x)|$ is just $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x)$. Therefore you can show a failure of uniform convergence by presenting an appropriate lower bound for these tails (since such a lower bound tells us that the rate of convergence is at least as slow as that of some other, simpler sequence). One such lower bound that you can furnish is the one I suggested. Think a little bit about how to get it (it is not that difficult...do a little algebra).

Comment: Why is |S$_n$(x) -S(x)|  equal to  ∑∞k=n+1fk(x) and what does ∑∞k=n+1 fk(x) mean???  I just can't understand why it isn't uniform convergence.

Comment: I define $f_k(x)=\frac{1}{x^k+1},S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x),S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$. (Or $k$ could start at $0$ or $52$ or whatever, it doesn't matter much.) Then simple algebra, and the positivity of the $f_k$, gives $|S_n(x)-S(x)|=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x)$. $|S_n(x)-S(x)|$ going to zero as $n \to \infty$ at fixed $x$ is pointwise convergence of $S_n$, which we already checked by providing an upper bound on it.

Comment: (Cont.) Since we see that there is a blowup in our upper bound as $x \to 1^+$, we guess maybe the convergence is not uniform. So we go looking for a lower bound. It is convenient to choose this lower bound to be another geometric series, and if you try to prove this bound you will find that you can do it.

Comment: Why do we need a lower bound??  I think this subject is too hard for me, because I really don't understand at all what the things you say have to do with seeing uniform conv

Comment: Showing $f_n \to f$ uniformly amounts to showing an upper bound: you need to present $N(\epsilon)$ such that $\| f_n - f \|_\infty < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N(\epsilon)$. If we negate that, we see that showing $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly amounts to showing a lower bound: you need to present a particular $\epsilon$ and infinitely many values of $n$ such that $\| f_n - f \|_\infty > \epsilon$.

Comment: (Cont.) So once you've concluded that the sequence isn't going to converge uniformly, it is just following logic and definitions to see that you need to cook up a lower bound. Concluding that the sequence is or isn't converging uniformly in the first place is more difficult, and takes some real practice.